# questions on defining and calling train.momentumoptimizer

Tags: tensorflow

I have some questions regarding the following code segment

```
def _optimizer(self,training_iters, global_step, opt_kwargs={}):
    learning_rate = self.opt_kwargs.pop("learning_rate", 0.2)
    decay_rate = self.opt_kwargs.pop("decay_rate", 0.95)
    self.learning_rate_node = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=learning_rate, 
                                                    global_step=global_step, 
                                                    decay_steps=training_iters,  
                                                    decay_rate=decay_rate, 
                                                    staircase=True)
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate_node, 
                                               **self.opt_kwargs).minimize(self.net.cost, 
                                                                            global_step=global_step)
```

The input pararameter of `opt_kwargs` is setup as `opt_kwargs=dict(momentum=0.2)`

Why we need to use `self.opt_kwargs.pop("learning_rate", 0.2)` to assign `learning_rate`. My guess is that this way can inject the learning rate and decay rate information into the dict structure of opt_kwargs. But I don't see the real usage here.

Secondly, regarding `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate_node, 
                                               **self.opt_kwargs)`, looks like `**self.opt_kwargs` will pass the whole `opt_kwargs` dict into the `MomentumOptimizer`. However, according to [tf.train.MomentumOptimizer.**init**(learning_rate, momentum, use_locking=False, name='Momentum', use_nesterov=False)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#MomentumOptimizer), it only needs the momentum value. Here, we are passing both `learning_rate` and `decay_rate` included in `self.opt_kwargs`. Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) The argument pop is so that you extract the `learning_rate` and `decay_rate` value and feed it to `exponential_decay()`, which accepts them as individual argument.  2.) It's not clean but is ok to feed in a dict with extra entries.  This makes it flexible so that ex. you can easily swap `MomentumOptimizer` with another optimizer that takes in decay_rate, etc as part of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

tf.train.MomentumOptimizer.init(learning_rate, momentum, use_locking=False, name='Momentum', use_nesterov=False) This means you need to explicitly pass a momentum value to the function. For self.opt_kwargs.pop, you do not need to pass a "learning_rate" or "decay_rate" to your function since they are set default using 0.2 and 0.95.